# create .ear using .war file with ANT script

Tags: jakarta-ee, ant

I have a web application. I need to create .ear file for it using ANT Build script. I have created .war file and tried to create .ear using it. But .ear syntax is expecting application.xml file which i don't have in my web application project.

Its a web project. But ANT ear syntax expecting appxml file. How to create a .ear file in this context ?

Answer (score 0):

The `<ear>` and `<war>` tasks are from the J2EE 1.4 era when deployment descriptors were required. The specs define the `.ear` and `.war` file formats to be regular JARs, so you're probably better off using `<jar>` directly for modern applications.

Comment: But my output should be x.ear file which supposed to be deployed in Websphere Portal Application Server. Do you mean <jar> syntax can achieve this functionality ?

Comment: Yes, an `.ear` file is just a JAR, so you can build one with `<jar>` and just include the `.war` file in it.